# For a Serializable super class, if we serialize the subclass, why does the super constructor is invoked

Tags: java, inheritance, serialization, constructor

```
import java.io.*;
class Animal implements Serializable
{
    String type;

    Animal()
    {
        System.out.println("Animal's default constructor");
    }
}


class Dog extends Animal
{
    int weight;
    Dog(String type, int weight)
    {
        this.type = type;
        this.weight = weight;
        System.out.println("running the Dog's dual arg'd constructor");
    }
}


class DogSerialized
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Dog d = new Dog("hairy",29);
        System.out.println(d.type+"  "+d.weight);
        try{
            FileOutputStream fs = new FileOutputStream("fileSerialized.ser");
            ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(fs);
            os.writeObject(d);
            os.close();
        }//end of try block
        catch(Exception e){}
        Dog d1 = null;

        try{
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("fileSerialized.ser");
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
            d1 = (Dog) ois.readObject();
        }//end of try block
        catch(Exception e){}
        System.out.println(d1.type+"  "+d1.weight);
    }
}
```

---

Running this code, I was able to see that the super's constructor was invoked. I don't get why/how was it invoked. Can you please explain this particular situation (Serializing-deserializing a subclass instance whose super is Serializable)

Comment: Please let me know if you need more info, in the comments here. I'm pretty much new to this forum.

Answer (score 1):

Its the code `Dog d = new Dog("hairy",29);` that is calling the super class constructor not the serialization process. Whenever you create an object of a child class, it calls constructor of its parent class.

Answer (score 1):

Your question has nothing to do with serialization. When any instance is created using `new` the constructors run. They don't run when an object is de-serialized.

A super class's constructor is called implicitly because the compiler will insert a no-arg call to `super();` for you, as the very first statement in the sub class's constructor. To understand this concept more clearly you have to know about **constructor chaining**. It is nothing but, in Java every constructor invokes the constructor
of its superclass with an implicit call to `super();` unless you call `this();` explicitly (refer overloaded construtors).

In your case, `Dog extends Animal` and `Animal extends Object` (because every class we create in Java will extend `Object` class).

Now, when you say `Dog d = new Dog("hairy",29);` in your main method, the following steps takes place

1. Firstly your `Dog` constructor is invoked. But it won't initialize
   your variables `type` and `weight` yet.
2. As the first statement in your Dog's constructor is `super();`
   (implicit), your `Animal` class's constructor is invoked.
3. Again the first statement in your Animal's constructor is `super();`
   (implicit) so `Object` class's constructor is invoked.
4. At this point we're on top of the stack because class `Object` in Java
   is at highest level in Inheritance hierarchy. So the Object
   constructor completes and pops out of the stack.
5. The next constructor in stack is `Animal`. It will complete the
   statements in it after the super(); statement and pops out of the
   stack.
6. The final constructor in stack is `Dog`. It will also complete all the
   remaining statements in it and pops out of the stack.

Coming to your example, when you call `Dog d = new Dog("hairy",29);` the compiler inserts `super();` as shown below

```
 Dog(String type, int weight)
    {
        super(); //You can also explicitly state this. This will invoke Animal() constructor before going to below statements.
        this.type = type;
        this.weight = weight;
        System.out.println("running the Dog's dual arg'd constructor");
    }
```

**Important points:**

1. The first statement in any constructor is an implicit call to
   `super();` or explicit call to `this();`
2. When you explicitly call `super();` the arguments in it should match
   with the super class constructor's parameters. For example, if your Animal constructor has 2 arguments like this `Animal(String type, int weight)` and you call `super();` in your Dog constructor you get compiler error.
3. Constructors are never inherited. They can't be overridden.

Answer (score 0):

Constructor is no inherited in the sub-class. So in order to create sub-class object, first the base (super-class) object need to be created by calling the super constructor (pretty normal as in your example). After super is created then the sub-class constructor is called to add any sub-class fields. Object is like anion: inner layers is the super class and outer layers is the sub-class.

You can read more about it in this [article](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076614/core-java/object-initialization-in-java.html).

Answer (score -1):

The interface, Serializable or not, does not have any influence about calling constructors.

Subclasses ALWAYS call the constructor of its parent, when they are created.

---

You can try changing Animal class to this :

```
class Animal implements Serializable
{
    String type;

    Animal(String something)
    {
        System.out.println("Animal's default constructor");
    }
}
```

The code will not compile, because in Dog constructor, you do not call constructor of its parent.

Comment: Max Zoom - really? And what would be the value of varibale "something"? :)

Comment: @MaxZoom - I said "if you CHANGE Animal class like I did it will not compile", look what I did with it, try it and it is true, it will not compile. Why it does not compile? Because child always call parent constructor...

Comment: The code will not compile because the compiler can't insert a `super()` call to the missing no-args constructor.